# insert data where all rows equals to null

Tags: sql

Is there a way to insert data where all rows are equals to null? I know it looks like

```
select login from Users
where login is null
```

When it return me

```
1. null
2. null
3. null
```

and so on...

How can I fill data to all this null rows?

Comment: Please edit your question an provide sample data and desired results.  Your query has a `select` statement, and that definitely won't do an `insert`.

Comment: What do you mean " where all rows are equals to null", you mean if there are no rows present?

Comment: And please tell us which database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To just update the null values in one column then do this;

```
UPDATE TableName
SET FieldName = ISNULL(FieldName,'NewValue')
```

If you want to update all columns when they ALL are NULL then you can do something like this

```
UPDATE TableName
SET 
     Field1 = 'Value1'
    ,Field2 = 'Value2'
    ,Field3 = 'Value3'
WHERE
    Field1 IS NULL 
    AND Field2 IS NULL
    AND Field3 IS NULL
```

If you want to replace all NULL values in the table regardless of whether the whole row is NULL then you can do this;

```
UPDATE TableName
SET
     Field1 = ISNULL(Field1,'Value1')
    ,Field2 = ISNULL(Field2,'Value2')
    ,Field3 = ISNULL(Field3,'Value3')
```

If you want to update the values to different values for each row you will need a way of linking a user to their login. A basic version would be something like this (I'm referring to this as LookupTable)

```
ID  Login
1   User1
2   User2
3   User3
```

Your query will be something like this;

```
UPDATE a
SET a.login = ISNULL(a.login,b.login)
FROM TableName a
JOIN LookupTable b
    ON a.id = b.id
```

This will only update values with a NULL but you'd probably want to just `set a.login = b.login` to ensure that all of your data is correct.

Comment: If I have for example 1000 amount of rows this will be too hard to write. Is there a different way to solve this problem?

Comment: Ok, but how many columns do you have? Field usually refers to an individual cell.

Comment: I've 6 column(Id, Name, Surname, E-Mail, Password, Login) and for example I've 1000 users where all logins are nulls

Comment: And do you have a table that contains each person's login and a link to this table (id maybe)? Also, what version of SQL are you using? (SQL Server, MySql, Oracle)

Comment: Nop, it doesn't. I'm using sql server

Comment: You're going to need to work out how you're going to work out how to populate this field, a join would be by far the easiest way of updating if you don't want it to all be updated to the same value. I'll update my answer shortly with an example of what I mean.

Comment: It would be nice if you will give me this example with same value :)

Comment: This site is here to help you learn. You're not going to learn anything if we just write all of the code for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Users 
SET login = 'value'
WHERE login is NULL
```

This would update the login column with the value 'value', if the current value is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all columns in a table can take `NULL` values and do not have defaults, you can insert a row into a table with all `NULL` values by doing:

```
insert into t(col)
    select NULL;
```

`insert` should have at least a single column; any column will do.

Comment: This would be just a single `NULL` row. I don't think this is what OP is looking for, since he said `"all rows equal to null"`. Nonetheless, he has to give more details.

Comment: I've update question, I need to insert data to all null rows in the table

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu . . . That appears to be what the OP wants.